# Morphism between surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose that $S$ is a surface of general type. Let $K_S$ the canonical bundle of $S$ and $\phi=\phi_{K_S}$ the canonical map. Suppose that the canonical map is a morphism from $S$ to $\mathbb{P}^{p_g-1}$ of degree 1.
Can i say that $\phi$ is an embedding between $S$ and its image in the projective space?

Comment: I've deleted my answer; I missed the condition that $\text{deg}\phi = 1$.